# How to emit 2D double array from mapper using TwoDArrayWritable

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I want to emit a 2D double array using `TwoDArrayWritable` as value .

how to write the `context.write(key ,  )`

**EDIT**

And in `Reducer` how to `get` them in a Two Dimensional double array and `print` the values.

I `Wrote` in  `Mapper`

```
row = E.length;
col = E[0].length;
                     TwoDArrayWritable array = new TwoDArrayWritable (DoubleWritable.class);
                     DoubleWritable[][] myInnerArray = new DoubleWritable[row][col];
                     // set values in myInnerArray
                     for (int k1 = 0; k1 < row; k1++) {
                        for(int j1=0;j1< col;j1++){
                            myInnerArray[k1][j1] = new DoubleWritable(E[k1][j1]);

                    }
                 array.set(myInnerArray);
                 context.write(clusterNumber, array);
```

But showing a `Nullpointer exception`

```
13/11/01 16:34:07 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Map task executor complete.
13/11/01 16:34:07 WARN mapred.LocalJobRunner: job_local724758890_0001
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:404)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.TwoDArrayWritable.write(TwoDArrayWritable.java:91)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.serializer.WritableSerialization$WritableSerializer.serialize(WritableSerialization.java:100)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.serializer.WritableSerialization$WritableSerializer.serialize(WritableSerialization.java:84)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer.collect(MapTask.java:945)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewOutputCollector.write(MapTask.java:601)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.TaskInputOutputContextImpl.write(TaskInputOutputContextImpl.java:85)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.map.WrappedMapper$Context.write(WrappedMapper.java:106)
    at edu.Mapper.map(Mapper.java:277)


Mapper.java:277 : context.write(clusterNumber, array);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 TwoDArrayWritable array = new TwoDArrayWritable (DoubleWritable.class);
 DoubleWritable[][] myInnerArray = new DoubleWritable[10][];
 // set values in myInnerArray
 array.set(myInnerArray);
 context.write(key, array);
```

I believe the NPE is because some element of the array is null. From the code you posted I wonder does `ecol` equal `col`.

Comment: oh sorry. that was a mistake while copy pasting. And my array contains value..i made it sure by printing the double array before emitting.so how it throws NPE

Comment: I would look at the source code of `TwoDWritableArary` for the version of Hadoop you are using and look at line 91. What is at the line that could be null / cause an NPE?

Comment: WOW..Thats great John B .The version of hadoop i am using is hadoop2 - cdh4.3 .

Comment: I didn't say I would do it for you

Comment: No no no I did nt mean so John ..I am going through tat.I told WOW becoz u gave me a hint to look into the source code of TwoDArrayWritable.

Comment: fixed :). a } played the game.

Comment: Hello user2922060!   How did you resolve the problem. Please specify what you did?

Answer (score 0):

Guys This NPE exception occured dew to some null value in your array. If any value not there in array than it will put null dew to object in nature. You can check this in debugging mode. So your task is to check there is no null value in your array.